# Python Pandas Pylab Seaborn: use Grid From Primary Y

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

How can I tell pylab/matplotlib/seaborn to use for the horizontal grid lines the values from the ***primary*** Y axis (and not from the secondary Y axis)?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pylab import plt
plt.style.use('seaborn')
df_x = pd.DataFrame({"a": [100, 200, 300], "b": [40, 5, 6]})
df_x.plot(figsize=(10, 6), secondary_y='b');
plt.show()
```

As visible below, with default settings the major ticks of the `secondary_y` axis are taken. So, looking at the primary (left) Y axis, the horizontal lines are at 100, 127, 160, 182, 210, 240, 272, 300.

[image: output]

Comment: "As visible" sorry, I don't understand the issue at all.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I (hopefully) made the question clearer.

Comment: documentation is at: [https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea would be to turn the grid off for the secondary axes and turn it on for the primary one.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn')
df_x = pd.DataFrame({"a": [100, 200, 300], "b": [40, 5, 6]})
ax = df_x.plot(figsize=(10, 6), secondary_y='b')

ax.grid(axis='y')
ax2 = ax.figure.axes[1]
ax2.grid(False)

plt.show()
```

[image]